# Creating random points using ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, random, large-datasets

I want to create 100 random datasets in ArcMap for a particular area. Each dataset should contain 10,000 random points. I am using the "Create Random Points" tool in ArcMap.

Can anyone suggest a method to create 100 datasets simultaneously, without processing again and again?

Comment: How long does it take to create one feature class with 10,000 random points in your configuration?

Comment: Could you please describe what specifications you have for the random datasets?

Comment: It's only a million points. Writing 100 simultaneous datasets wold take longer to set up (longer than serial execution, probably) and *way* longer to run (due to IO saturation), and the resulting feature classes will be badly fragmented (and therefore access slower). There is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use python. Adjust the paths and [parameters](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-random-points.htm).

```
import arcpy, os

out_fgdb = r'C:\folder\data.gdb'
constraining_feature_class = r'C:\folder\datadata.gdb\polygons'

for n in range(1, 101):
    print 'Processing {0} of 100'.format(n)
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(out_path=out_fgdb, out_name='dataset_{}'.format(n), constraining_feature_class=constraining_feature_class, number_of_points_or_field=10000)
```